# Do Java Executors run in a daemon thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I had a short java program that created a single thread scheduled executor and I scheduled a task.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

scheduledExecutorService.schedule(cloudWatchReporter, accumulateForMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Before the scheduled time arrived, my main thread ended and the JVM exited.  I had expected that it would wait for the timer to complete and the scheduled task to execute before shutting down.  This is not what happened.  If I added a sufficient sleep just before my main thread ended  my task would then execute before the JVM shut down.

Do Executors have a master thread that manages the timer?  Or is the timer effect achieved in some other way?  If managed by some master thread, is it a daemon thread or a non-daemon thread?

Comment: See the javadoc of `defaultThreadFactory()`: _Returns a default thread factory used to create new threads. This factory creates all new threads used by an Executor in the same ThreadGroup. [...] **Each new thread is created as a non-daemon thread** with priority set to the smaller of Thread.NORM_PRIORITY and the maximum priority permitted in the thread group. [...]_

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I did not ask if the threads in the pool are daemon or non-daemon.  I asked if a thread exists which creates the threads for the pool and if that thread is daemon or non-daemon.

Comment: All of the threads in the JDK's implementation of `ScheduledExecutorService` pull tasks from the master "queue". There is no "managing" thread. Threads are created and started as needed (and up to a max, 1 in your case) from the thread calling any of the `schedule` methods.

Comment: How does the timer run?

Comment: Each thread loops trying to take from a shared priority queue, sleeping the duration of the topmost element (if present), more or less.

Answer (score 5):

This simple complete example contradicts what you're claiming in your question:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> System.out.println("hello"), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Run it, and you'll see that not only the message is printed after 10 seconds, but the program doesn't exit. So your main thread didn't simply end. You probably call `System.exit()`.

Comment: I ran the code you provided.  It works as you said.  But I can't get those two lines in the main method to run  the same way when executed as part of a JUnit test.  The test just exits before the text "hello" is printed.  Does JUnit test code run differently than executing from a main method?  I didn't mention it before but my original call to the schedule method happens from a JUnit test.

Comment: The JUnit executor most probably calls System.exit() as soon as all the tests have been executed. If you want the sheduled job to run, you need to block the test for a long enough duration.